# Trying to use updateOne(). req.body.attribute returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a to do list using node, mongodb, and express. I'm trying to update a todo so when I click on it, it applies a class for css. I can't get it to update. It doesn't give me an error but console logging `req.body.done` returns undefined, which leads me to believe that `$set` is not working.

It's probably really simple and I'm not seeing it.

Server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const cors = require("cors");
const { request } = require("mongodb");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(cors());

const username = "hidden";
const password = "hidden";
const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.7k2ww.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(
  (client) => {
    console.log("Connected to database");

    const db = client.db("to-do-list");
    const toDoCollection = db.collection("to-dos");

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static("public"));

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      toDoCollection
        .find()
        .toArray()
        .then((result) => {
          res.render("index.ejs", { todos: result });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });

    app.post("/addtodo", (req, res) => {
      toDoCollection
        .insertOne({ todo: req.body.todo, done: false })
        .then((result) => {
          res.redirect("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });

    app.put("/markComplete", (req, res) => {
      toDoCollection
        .updateOne(
          {
            todo: req.body.todo,
          },
          {
            $set: { done: true }, // <--- could be not working but not returning an error
          },
          { upsert: false }
        )
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(req.body.todo);
          console.log(req.body.done); // <--- not working here and returns undefined
          res.json("Task completed");
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });

    app.delete("/deletetodo", (req, res) => {
      toDoCollection
        .deleteOne({ todo: req.body.todo })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("todo deleted");
          res.json("todo deleted");
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  }
);
```

main.js:

```
const deleteTask = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-todo");
const completeTask = document.querySelectorAll(".complete-task");

Array.from(deleteTask).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", deleteToDoFunc);
});

Array.from(completeTask).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", completeToDoFunc);
});

async function deleteToDoFunc() {
  console.log("Delete working!");
  const todo = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;

  try {
    const res = await fetch("deleteToDo", {
      method: "delete",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todo: todo,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function completeToDoFunc() {
  console.log("Update working!");
  const todo = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;

  try {
    const res = await fetch("markComplete", {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todo: todo,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>To Do</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="flexContainer">
        <h1 class="title main-font center">To Do List</h1>
      </header>

      <form class="center" action="/addtodo" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To Do" name="todo" />
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
      </form>

      <div class="to-do-list flexContainer">
        <ul class="task-list center">
          <% for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {%>
          <li class="todo-name main-font complete-task">
            <% if (todos[i].done === true) { %>
              <span class="done"><%= todos[i].todo %></span>
            <% } else { %>
              <span><%= todos[i].todo %></span>
            <% } %>
            <span class="fa fa-trash delete-todo"></span>
          </li>
          <%} %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(req.body.done); // <--- not working here and returns undefined
```

Did you send the value for `Done` in `req.body`. I think you are not sending Hence showing undefined.  If you want to check the updated `Done` value then check  the result `(Modified count)`